# How to print selected value of radio button?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-forms

Can you please tell me how to print selected value of radio button ?
I tried like this but it not work?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grtvc7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="favoriteName">
  <mat-radio-button  *ngFor="let name of names" [value]="name">
    {{name}}
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>

<div class="example-selected-value">Your favorite season is: {{favoriteName}}</div>
```

this example not work for me ..

Can you suggest another ay to do this  ? because I don't want to use **[(ngModel)]** ?
But first why it is not working using **ngmodel**

Comment: Just remove the from element , it 's will work

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using form tag You need to name tag for form elements

```
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="favoriteName" name="something">
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uwhqbm?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: any other way to do this without using `ngModel`

Comment: you can do this using form control

Comment: how can you share ur fiddle

Answer (score 0):

If you are using form tagyou must name yor form elements as @Sachila Ranawaka said or you can add ngModelOptions like

```
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="favoriteName"  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
  <mat-radio-button  *ngFor="let name of names" [value]="name">
    {{name}}
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>

<div class="example-selected-value">Your favorite season is: {{favoriteName}} </div>
</form>
```

if you check there is an error in you console exmplane all of this

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to give a `name` attribute to `mat-radio-group`

```
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="favoriteName" name="fav">
  <mat-radio-button  *ngFor="let name of names" [value]="name">
    {{name}}
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>

<div class="example-selected-value">Your favorite season is: {{favoriteName}}</div>
</form>
```

**[Demo](https://angular-tvc2ah.stackblitz.io/)**